# Disable a particular legend in a line chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, legend, linechart, lineseries

Is there any possibility to disable a particular legend for LineSeries component in a line chart.

Let say that we have the following code:

```
<mx:Panel title="Line Chart">
 <mx:LineChart id="myChart" 
    dataProvider="{expenses}" 
    showDataTips="true"
 >
    <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis 
            dataProvider="{expenses}" 
            categoryField="Month"
        />
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:series>
       <mx:LineSeries 
            yField="Profit" 
            displayName="Profit"
       />
       <mx:LineSeries 
            yField="Expenses" 
            displayName="Expenses"
       />
    </mx:series>
 </mx:LineChart>
 <mx:Legend id="legend" dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
```

It will produce the following line chart:

[image]

And this the result that i want:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Bare in mind that I have to use the legend's DataProvider as myChart because the data is dynamically build. Also, the legend is customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, as i have custom legend I have to set the data provider legend after updating the line chart:

```
 // Add listener event to the linechart component for when the legend update completes so it can filter lineseries on the legend's dataprovider in [onUpdateLegendComplete]
    myChart.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, onUpdateLinechartComplete);
```

And the function is:

```
protected function onUpdateLinechartComplete(e:FlexEvent):void 
{
    legend.dataProvider = myChart.legendData[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead using your chart as DataProvider, you could create individual LegendItems

```
    <mx:Legend>
        <mx:LegendItem label="Profit" fill="#e48701">           
        </mx:LegendItem>
    </mx:Legend>
```

edit2: try this

```
    <mx:Legend dataProvider="{new ArrayCollection(myChart.legendData).getItemAt(0)}">
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i just want to use the DataProvider for the legend as the data is dynamically built

Comment: see the edit. Could you be bit more specific about the data: do the legends change?

Comment: First, the second solution didn't work: the legendItems object is always empty as i dynamically set the data. About the data, i read it from XML file. That's why i don't know exactly the lineseries just i have a property that i could use it do not showing the legend. 
Is any property could be related to lineseries component itself ?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing. See another edit, does that work? Do you need X amount of legends or just the "Profit", no matter how many lineseries there are.

Comment: Yes It is fine i could show only the first legend just by using callLater function. But when applying this solution the custom legend item is not applied. Do you know the cause? thanks

Comment: The problem is exactly here `this.setStyle("legendMarkerRenderer", customLegend);`. The classfactory is not applied or the property legendMarkerRenderer does not exist but before it works fine without amending the legend dataprovider

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://flexdevtips.blogspot.com/2009/10/linechart-with-checkbox-legend.html It might give you some ideas.